# Creating Universal Padding/Inset for UITextField in xCode 6.1 (Swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

How do you create padding for text field (UITextField) in swift? I want it to be global scope so when the UIView load every Text field have this padding apply to it.

**Current Swift Code:**

```
class MyCustomTextField: UITextField {
 // Custom Code that i can't figure out.
}
```

**Steps i try to take:**

- Apple developer document, it doesn't talk about inset or padding
  override
- Search Stackoverflow and see they either relate to objective-c or the
  hack is removed when Xcode become 6.1
- Google, nothing came up about Swift padding (only objective-c)

Thank you in Advanced. 
Swift Beginner :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyCustomTextField : UITextField {
    var leftMargin : CGFloat = 10.0

    override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var newBounds = bounds
        newBounds.origin.x += leftMargin
        return newBounds
    }

    override func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var newBounds = bounds
        newBounds.origin.x += leftMargin
        return newBounds
    }
}
```